# C++ function overload for classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have 3 classes

```
class A { 
//...
}

class B : public A {
//...
}
```

And a class C:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

class C
{
   void method(A anObjOfA);
   void method(B anObjOfB);
}
```

Now if I do

```
B* ptr = new B();
A* ptrToB = ptr;
c.method(*ptrToB);
```

It calls the method for Objects of type A, not the inherited actual type B.. How can I make sure the right function for the object deepest in the inheritence-tree is called, without actually knowing it's type at compile-time?

PS: I'm sure this is a noob question, for the life of me I can't find any results on this here, as everyone is busy understanding the "virtual" keyword, which is perfectly clear to me but is not the issue here.

Comment: Did you mean to provide `virtual` methods with `class A` , or a pure `virtual` interface?

Comment: Why do you think `virtual` is not an issue here ?

Comment: What you are looking for is called [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), and it's not included in C++. However, you can re-architect your classes such that `method` is a virtual method on `A`, with a different implementation in `B`, and get rid of `C` entirely. Then (with C++'s single dynamic dispatch), calling `method` on the instance will ensure the correct version is called. @πάνταῥεῖ: Neither. Read the question.

Comment: @Cameron I've been posting this comment, even before the question's _PS:_ part was written. Anyway the OP's unclear about the point, why `virtual` shouldn't be used.

Comment: Well C is actually a very big class that handles a lot of management of other classes, among them them a baseclass A and several classes that inherit some methods&attributes from A. (Call them B1...B8)
But because these classes are functionally very different apart from the methods shared with their ancestor I need to treat them very different when calling the above 'method'.

Comment: @Cameron your comment about 'multiple dispatch' is exactly right, since I mostly use Objective-C which does exactly this. I think I just applied the same thought patterns as in Objective-C to this issue here and therefore got stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @texasbruce I found the answer, [RTTI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI)

The code will look like this:

```
A* someAOrBPtr = ...
...
B* testBPtr = dynamic_cast<B*>(someAOrBPtr);
if( testBPtr ){
    // our suspicions are confirmed -- it really was a B
    C->method(testBPtr);
}else{
    // our suspicions were incorrect -- it is definitely not a B.
    // The someAOrBPtr points to an instance of some other child class of the base A.
    C->method(someAOrBPtr);
};
```

EDIT: In fact, I'll probably do the dynamic cast inside the C->method so there is only one

> C::method(A* ptrOfBase)

and then do the appropriate thing (taking in or out the respective container-member-variable of C) inside the one 'method' of C.

Comment: This will work but be aware use of dynamic_cast can mean a bad design.

Comment: I know it's not very elegant, If I could think of a good way to restructure it so that your answer would apply, I'd prefer that too. Have you seen my two comments under your answer? 
If you can think of a better more elegant solution to the details layed out, I'm all yours :)

Comment: I would need to know more about what you are actually doing. The example is too abstract.

Answer (score 5):

Because resolving a function overload is done at compile-time. When you call the function it only sees the `A` part of the pointer, even though it could point to a B.

Perhaps what you want is the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void DoWorkInC()
    {
        cout << "A's work";
    }
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void DoWorkInC()
    {
        cout << "B's work";
    }
};

class C
{
   void method(A& a)
   {
        a.DoWorkInC();
   }
}
```

Comment: Well this is an approach that I was thinking about, yet it's not that simple, as C has different containers that behave differently for different subclasses of A. Among other things one 'method' was the method that takes the respective subclass of A out of it's respective container structure.

Comment: To explain this further one subclass of A (call it B1) is quite simple, it is just stored inside a 'std::vector' and deleted when taken out.
Another one (B2) is stored in an elaborate gridlike structure for performance sake (B2 had to optimized because it is accessed spacially). 
Another B3's pointer may be inside both a gridlike structure but also in a 'vector' for fast complete iteration and needs to be taken out of both if removed.

Answer (score 0):

Let your class A, B have virtual function implemented in their respectivbe classes:

```
class A { 
//...
   public:
     virtual void doTask(); 
};

class B : public A {
//...
   public:
     void doTask(); 
};
```

Ket A::doTask() and B::doTask() do respective tasks in object specific way, i.e. A::doTask() to do tasks with visibility of the object set as an A object, and B::doTask() to do tasks with visibility of the object set as an B object.
Now, let the call be like this:

```
B* ptr = new B();
A* ptrToB = ptr;
c.method(ptrToB); // pointer is passed
```

Within C::method(A *ptr), it may be something like:

```
void C::method(A * ptr) {
  ptr->doTask(); this would actuall call A::doTask() or B::doTask() as dynamically binded
}
```

Comment: same thing as Neil Kirks answer, same comment.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is not smart enough to guess which method you wanna call. In the same situation of yours, you might actually want to call the the first version since you are using a `A*`. This leaves the programmer to work on: be specific. If you don't want to use `ptr` (which call the second version as you wished), you need to specifically cast it:

```
c.method(*((B*)ptrToB));
```

or better using dynamic cast:

```
c.method(*dynamic_cast<B*>(ptrToB));
```

This could be unsafe because you are "downcasting" in which case dynamic cast may throw exception and C style cast won't but will cause memory leak. You have to be very careful.

Comment: What? You should use C++ cast, especially dynamic_cast. And what is the memory leak?

Comment: dynamic cast sounds like exactly the thing I should be using.

Comment: @neilkirk in this case it won't, but it might if you are passing the wrong object.

Comment: @NeilKirk If you have a base object, but you cast it to an inherited object, and you trying to access a field in the inherited object which does not exist in the base object. (again not this case)

Comment: I am referring to the memory leak.